# Google cloud platform node js app can't connect to mLab

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, google-cloud-platform

I have a node.js web app using express that I managed to upload to google cloud platform using git. I use mongoose to connect to a remote database from mLab. I have user credentials and the URI is correct for sure because if I try to run the app locally (using the remote mLab mongoDB) it works just fine but if I try to start the app from gcloud shell it gives me the following:

```
Express app listening on port 8080
(node:845) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [ds123658.mlab.com:23658] on first
 connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to ds123658.mlab.com:23658 timed out]
(node:845) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js proce
ss with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is how i connect to the database using mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


//mongodb connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb://*****:*****@ds123658.mlab.com:23658/englishfiles");
```

I've censored the username and password but I am sure these are not the problem
This is my first time I am deploying an app so what am I missing?

Comment: it seems like it can`t connect to that mongoose, and it just times out. maybe the URL is wrong.

Comment: but why when i run the same URL("mongodb://*****:*****@ds123658.mlab.com:23658/englishfiles") locally it works just fine?

Comment: You said you uploaded your app to Google Cloud Platform. Is it residing on a VM instance in Compute Engine? Can you access any other URL outside of your app? Maybe you need to enable outgoing/incoming traffic for the necessary ports